# Ubuntu Touch -Adding photos to Instragram

Tags: ubuntu-touch

My son has an Instragram account and can see photos from his instragram Scope. I have had a look but it does not seem possible to add photos to your account in Ubuntu Touch. Has this changed and is there a way my son can add photos to his instragram account from his Ubuntu Touch tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last few weeks, I have been using the new Instagram app for Touch (Instagraph).This has allowed me to add photos to my Instergram account via the device galary. As yet, I have been unable to take a photo directly and then load it up my account. For now, this is a great step forward and means that Ubuntu Touch can be used with Instagram accounts.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see the last update is that Instragram don’t offer an upload API’s to the Ubuntu developers. As a result, they have only been able to create a superb Instragram Scope that allows you to read and leave comments, like images, view account details and a few more options, but not load your own photos. Hopefully, this will change soon and the upload API’s will find their way to the developers. When they do, the Scope will be tip top.

Comment: I must admit that it doesn't seem that there currently is no way of adding pictures into your account from the scope. Hopefully this will chqnge soon. Or there is the way through the desktop with an app. Hwever, that is not much use to my son currently.